# LibreOffice Calc crashes when dialog window is open

Tags: libreoffice

Just seen several times: When I open a dialog window in LibreOffice Calc (for example, in order to save a table as .csv or after right-click and then choosing "Format Cells"), the window flickers and then Ubuntu crashes, going back to "Scanning for btrfs file system", and then the Ubuntu login appears.

Here is the dmesg output:

```
[39325.939024] [drm] stuck on render ring
[39325.940137] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 7:0:0x87d77c3e, in Xorg [21731], reason: Ring hung, action: reset
[39325.942658] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[39333.938858] [drm] stuck on render ring
[39333.939977] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 7:0:0x85dffffc, in Xorg [21731], reason: Ring hung, action: reset
[39333.943197] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
```

It's curious that this error only occurs with LibreOffice, and only after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS.

Edit 1: My machine:

```
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 7709MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) 2955U @ 1.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1400MHz
          capacity: 1400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Edit 2: No crashes lately, but the display is still weird.

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice Calc]

Edit 3: I installed `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and later `mesa-utils`, and both do not change the appearance of LibreOffice.

Comment: What are your machine specs?

Comment: Just added them. Are some useful specs missing?

Comment: Thank for mentioning `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. It fixed in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a clean re-install of 16.04, and the problem doesn't occur anymore. I battled with Libreoffice when it ran on 16.04, upgraded from 15.10 by `do-release-upgrade -d`.

It seems the upgrade wasn't that clean...

Whether it's Impaled Impala 8.10 or another release, IMHO one should rather do a backup of all important directories and then a clean re-install instead of upgrading Ubuntu.